# How do I display complete message in log file while executing Invoke -Restmethod "multipoint/point data"

Tags: powershell, api, logging

I have a Powershell script and it has a Invoke-RestMethod code for sending a file over API to a URL.

Code is shown below

```
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls;
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -Uri $Uri -InFile $FilePath >> $Log
```

Now while appending the return response to the "Log" file, I get the following format

```
success data                                                                                                                                
------- ----                                                                                                                                
   True @{created=0; updated=0; skipped=0; unchanged=19; uploaded=19; errors=0; statusUrl=https://sandbox.myurl.com/Services/Conta...
```

The URL is not complete. This return message is generated as incomplete.

I require it in the below format

[image]

Could anyone help me get this thing going on?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the mesage is incomplete, merely truncated. Try replacing `>> $Log` by `| Format-List` or `| Format-Table -Wrap` to see the statusUrl in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code did the trick

```
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls;
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -Uri $Uri -InFile $FilePath
    $response
    $response.success >> $Log
    $response.data >> $Log
    $response.numRows >> $Log
    $response[0] >> $Log
```

As I was logging the response, I had to use the >>$Log to append the log file